Как передать значение из цвета из внешнего объекта в props компонентов?
подскажите пожалуйста, как пробросить значение цвета из внешнего объекта в компонент и применить его к объекту непосредственно? В данном случае у меня цвета хранятся в файле Color.jsx, я их подключаю к корневому компоненту и хочу пробросить в ItemCard, а через него и в Btn, но ничего не происходит...
Пересмотрел кучу гайдов и не могу понять, как именно пропсы работают.
UPD: исправил регистр благодаря комментаторам, теперь выдает ошибку Cannot read property "active" of undefined. Она находится в корневом компоненте и если убрать проброс пропса itemCard, то все хотя бы работает. Но как тогда передать пропс?
import Color from '../constansts/Color.jsx'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={BasicStyles.container}>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          <Header/>
          <HomeSlider/>
          <ItemCard color={Color.active}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default function ItemCard(props) {
    return (
        <View>
          <Btn color={props.Color.active}/>
        </View>
    )
}

export default function Btn(props) {
    return (
        <Pressable style={ButtonStyles.wrapper} color={props.color.active}>
    )
}


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Исправил, спасибо, не знал, как код читаемым сделать

<ItemCard color={Color.active}/> передаешь color маленькими буквами, принимаешь <Btn color={props.Color.active}/> - с большой буквы.

Не понял. Если в первом случае передать с маленькой, тогда не возьмется значение из внешнего объекта вроде, разве нет?

javaScript - регистрозависим Color !== color. Вы импортируете Color и в ItemCard передаете props color(color={}). В itemCard вы берете уже props.Color которого нет.

В место <Btn color={props.Color.active}/> напиши <Btn color={props.color.active}/>. Так понятнее? :)

Да, проверю и дам знать об  итогах, спасибо)

@ksa т.к. props.color это Color.active, то передавать в Btn надо  color={props.color}. Вроде так, если я ничего не упустил. Хотя ктож его знает, что такое Color и как оно выглядит в дейтсвительности

@SwaD, да с active там тоже ерунда...

@SwaD Color — объект без массива с названиями цветов в качестве ключей и их HEX-кодами в качестве значений

Проблема решилась — просто импортировал объект Color, запихнул его значения в массив с контентом, ибо компонент рендерится через map и вызывал конкретные значения уже из этого массива через пропсы конкретных элементов.
